# Can someone please explain this if statement array("options" => array("min_range"=>$min, "max_range"=>$max))) === false)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP and reading about PHP and cannot make sense of this if statement containing an array within an array. If someone could explain this in easy terms, that would be great:

```
 if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$min, "max_range"=>$max))) === false){ 

echo ("this is not in legal range");}
else { echo ("this is in legal range");}
```

Comment: The manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php is a bit difficult to understand for the filter_var function, especially for newcomers, but it's essentially just checking that $int is an integer and is in a certain range (between $min and $max). filter_var() will either return the value of $int if all checks are passed, or will return FALSE if they don't. To be honest that code is far too complex for the job it's doing so it's no wonder it's left you confused.

Comment: I wish I could write that last line of your comment on top of every php.net/manual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats an very complicated way to test if `$int` is an integer and is between `$min` and `$max`.

This should be the same as this.

```
if (is_int($int) && $int >= $min && $int <= $max) {
   // this is a valid range
} else {
   // this is a invalid range
}
```

Arrays inside arrays are a commonly used technique. You could nest as many arrays as you want, to create data structures.

Comment: From what I understand, the first array is acting like a pointer to the inner array. The inner array, in turn, has some options which the pointer then iterates to check if the number lies within those bounds? So complicated!

Answer (score 0):

> filter_var — Filters a variable with a specified filter

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

> FILTER_VALIDATE_INT   "int"   default, min_range, max_range   FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_HEX  Validates value as integer, optionally from the specified range, and converts to int on success.

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

it simply filters the variable - using a validation filter to check if it's an integer between the min and max values.

Comment: I should have been more clear with my question, sorry about that. I'm trying to understand why the PHP manual tries to do it using the two dimensional array as it does in the code above. I do understand that it's actually validating that the int lies within a given range

Comment: It's just that the function accepts an options array, which again (depending on which options you're going to use) accepts one or more sub arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$min, "max_range"=>$max))) === false){ 

echo ("this is not in legal range");}
else { echo ("this is in legal range");}
```

**Explanation :**

[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) - Filters a variable with a specified filter..

[FILTER_VALIDATE_INT](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_int.asp) - Check if the variable $int is an integer.

So, in that  `if condition` it is checking if the array contains the integer value and if the value of `$int` falls in the range(`$min` and `$max` ) values .

**Example :**

```
$int = 999999999999999999;
$min = 1;
$max = 2147483647;

if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options"=>
    array("min_range"=>$min, "max_range"=>$max))) === false) {
    echo("Variable value is not within the legal range");
} else {
    echo("Variable value is within the legal range");
}
//This will output "Variable value is not within the legal range"
```

Comment: Okay. But could you please explain why they need to put it in two arrays to get that result? I'm trying to understand the structure of the code

Comment: It is one way of doing the task. If you have array of result then it will be far better to check .